# Trigger created with compilation error for CREATE DDL statement : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a CREATE ddl trigger with a list of create table operations for exchange and partitions :

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_bug
AFTER CREATE ON DATABASE
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE dep (
         dep_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
         dep_nm VARCHAR2(30),
         c_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL)
         PARTITION BY HASH(dep_id)
         (PARTITION t1 tablespace tbs2);
CREATE TABLE dep_temp AS SELECT * from dep where 1=2;
ALTER TABLE dep EXCHANGE PARTITION t1 WITH TABLE dep_temp
WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
create table t1_temp for exchange with table dep;
ALTER TABLE dep
EXCHANGE PARTITION t1
WITH TABLE t1_temp
WITHOUT VALIDATION;
END;
/
```

I am getting the following error :

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"
```

Please suggest if this is the correct way to create a DDL command trigger.

---

Edit:

```
CREATE TRIGGER abc
AFTER CREATE ON DATABASE
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line( ora_dict_obj_name);
IF ora_dict_obj_name='DEP3' THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'CREATE TABLE dep (
             dep_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
             dep_nm VARCHAR2(30),
             c_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL)
       PARTITION BY HASH(dep_id)
       (PARTITION t1 tablespace tbs2)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'CREATE TABLE dep_temp AS SELECT * from dep where 1=2';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'ALTER TABLE dep
    EXCHANGE PARTITION t1
    WITH TABLE dep_temp
    WITHOUT VALIDATION
    UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'create table t1_temp for exchange with table dep';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'ALTER TABLE dep
EXCHANGE PARTITION t1
WITH TABLE t1_temp
WITHOUT VALIDATION';
END IF;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE dep3(
             dep_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
             dep_nm VARCHAR2(30),
             c_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL);
```

I have updated the trigger definition and the requirement is to exit out of the trigger after dep3 is created but it again goes in a recursive loop.
Please suggest

Comment: You can't issue DDL as static SQL within PL/SQL; but why would you want to do this for *any* create - including the ones *within* the trigger, which will loop! - and what do you expect to happen on the second object creation, when `dep` already exists? It might help to explain what you're really trying to do, and why.

Comment: Trigger `AFTER CREATE ON DATABASE` will fire after **any** create statement, e.g. create a USER, VIEW, etc. The DDL statements don't make any sense. Why do you exchange a partition of an **empty** table?

Comment: PL/SQL has no `'CREATE'` keyword. You'll need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @AlexPoole is there a way I can add a "if" condition where it just executes the trigger for the create table query which is activating it for the first time. Please suggest.

Comment: @LearningToCode - I think you're looking for [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-F6473AD0-75D2-4E36-8B15-F93F0B5A8B799B); particularly `ora_dict_obj_name` which you can use to look for an existing object. Are you sure you want a database trigger rather than a schema trigger? Or a trigger at all - why not just create the permanent object `dep` once before you create anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is your exact requirement, but you can't use DDL directly in PL/SQL block. You can use a dynamic query when it is a DDL in PL/SQL.

so you need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to for any DDL in PL/SQL as follows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table .....';
```

Comment: That helped. Also, how to get the table name firing the trigger for the first time so that I can put an "if" condition before executing the trigger again.

Comment: You can use `ora_dict_obj_name` to know the name of table within trigger.

Comment: I used an if condition after the begin inside the trigger 
"IF ora_dict_obj_type='dep3' THEN". Dep3 is the table which is initiating the trigger. But when I print the ora_dict_obj_type, it prints "TABLE"/ Please suggest.

Comment: `'dept3'` must be `'DEPT3'` and `ora_dict_obj_type` will be return `TABLE`. If you want table name then `ora_dict_obj_name` should be used.